# Auto-correct in Mavericks for Romanian Dictionary

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization, spellcheck, autocorrect

I installed a Romanian dictionary on Mavericks in two ways:

1. by using the [cocoAspell](http://people.ict.usc.edu/~leuski/cocoaspell/) and,
2. by [copying the OpenOffice dictionary files](http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2011/06/extra-spell-checking-dictionaries-for.html) {aff|dic} in the ~/Library/Spelling/.

**The Good**: In both the cases, the the spell checker works well and underlines incorrectly spelled words. I report on my experience with TextEdit, but the same is probably true for other apps.

**The Bad**: It seems that auto-correct only works for non system dictionaries. For French if I type "bbientot" the system automatically fixes the word by removing the double b and adding the missing accent -> "bientôt". When I try the same thing for Romanian (e.g. "ddomnule") although the word is underlined, and the first suggestion in the contextual menu correctly removes the double d, the word is not automatically fixed.

**The Uncool**: This works well on the iPad and it's a shame that it does not work on my more powerful machine. If this would work one would then be able to write without diacritics and get them for free through auto-correction in languages that make heavy use of them (Romanian being one such language).

Is there anything that I am missing?

Note: System Preferences>Keyboard>Text>Correct spelling automatically is *checked* I still can't get the auto-correct to work. The "Check Spelling While Typing" and "Correct Spelling Automatically" from the Edit menu are also checked.

Comment: Have you check the bottom of the Edit menu in the app you are using to see if the right things are checked there?

Comment: Hi Tom! Indeed, the "Check Spelling While Typing" and "Correct Spelling Automatically" from the Edit menu are checked. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you expect autocorrect to work. What app is in the foreground? Where precisely are you typing (finder tags, finder renaming a file, spotlight search, etc...) - what sort of typo (exact characters) do you want to get corrected?

Comment: Are you talking about English?  If something else, what?

Comment: tomg and bmike: i've finally got some time to investigate the problem a bit more. i've edited the text to clarify your questions :)

Comment: Cocoaspell stuff has been obsolete for awhile.  If possible, use an OpenOffice dictionary instead.  http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2011/06/extra-spell-checking-dictionaries-for.html  Even so, I think autocorrect may only work right with dictionaries supplied by Apple.

Comment: thanks tom! indeed, i tried the OpenOffice dictionary instead, and still not success.